# Running Dart tests on the real database in Aqueduct

Tags: database, dart, aqueduct

I'm creating a read only PostgreSQL database. Since it won't be modified after I populate it, I'd like to run some tests to make sure the data is good. The TestHarness with the ORM mixin creates an empty database for each test. Can I access the real database from the tests?

*I'm moving a Q&A from the Aqueduct Slack channel for public reference.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Reductions](https://aqueductdart.slack.com/archives/C6A69KL8K/p1580135042003500?thread_ts=1579834022.002500&cid=C6A69KL8K):

> You can start a server and get its mangedContext.:
>
> ```
> final app = Application<YourChannel>() 
>   ..options.configurationFilePath = theConfigString 
>   ..options.port = somePort;
> await app.startOnCurrentIsolate();
> final context = app.channel.context; 
> // Now you can use the context to access the data base
> ```

And this is how I implemented it in context:

```
import "package:test/test.dart";
import 'package:my_server/model/text_line.dart';
import '../harness/app.dart';

Future main() async {

  // setup
  final app = Application<MyServerChannel>()
    ..options.configurationFilePath = 'config.yaml';
  await app.startOnCurrentIsolate();
  final context = app.channel.context;

  test('Database has the right number of rows', () async {
    final query = Query<TextLine>(context);
    final numRows = await query.reduce.count();
    expect(numRows, 43845);
  });

}
```